# How to fetch URL Posts from FB, Twitter and LinkedIn API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I'm looking to build a solution where I will be having a mobile app. This mobile app will connect to users all social networks namely Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter.

The app is intended to fetch posts of all friends on social network and combine it as single feed/timeline. The app should fetch only those posts which include URL in it. The application should read all of these URLs and fetch the metadata for the same.

Do APIs of all social network provide this capability to fetch only those Posts with URL of all friends with whom I'm connected?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 5):

yes these all social media sides provides their api to fetch user post also provide post type i-e link, statuses , post etc I m giving you a reference of facebook api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed